# Multiple line comments in WebAssembly

Tags: comments, webassembly

Is there any way to write a several-lines comment in `Wasm` (`wat`)? I know that `;;` is used for a one-line comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is, it is `(; ;)`: These comments can also be nested.

```
(;  
my
multi (; line ;)
comment   
;)
```

It is written in the [specification](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/text/lexical.html#comments) Section 6.2.4 (Text Format - Lexical Format - Comments).